# Google Cloud DLP - CSV inspection

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I'm trying to inspect a CSV file and there are no findings being returned (I'm using the EMAIL_ADDRESS info type and the addresses I'm using are coming up with positive hits here: https://cloud.google.com/dlp/demo/#!/).  I'm sending the CSV file into `inspect_content` with a `byte_item` as follows:

```
byte_item: {
  type: :CSV,
  data: File.open('/xxxxx/dlptest.csv', 'r').read
}
```

In looking at the supported file types, it looks like CSV/TSV files are inspected via Structured Parsing.

- For CSV/TSV does that mean one can't just sent in the file, and needs to use the `table` attribute instead of `byte_item` as per https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/inspecting-structured-text?
- What about for XSLX files for example?  They're an unspecified file type so I tried with a configuration like so, but it still returned no findings:

```
byte_item: {
  type: :BYTES_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED,
  data: File.open('/xxxxx/dlptest.xlsx', 'rb').read
}
```

I'm able to do inspection and redaction with images and text fine, but having a bit of a problem with other file types.  Any ideas/suggestions welcome!  Thanks!

Edit:  The contents of the CSV in question:

```
$ cat ~/Downloads/dlptest.csv 
dylans@gmail.com,anotehu,steve@example.com
blah blah,anoteuh,
aonteuh,

$ file ~/Downloads/dlptest.csv 
~/Downloads/dlptest.csv: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

The full request:

```
parent = "projects/xxxxxxxx/global"
inspect_config = {
  info_types: [{name: "EMAIL_ADDRESS"}],
  min_likelihood: :POSSIBLE,
  limits: { max_findings_per_request: 0 },
  include_quote: true
}
request = {
  parent: parent,
  inspect_config: inspect_config,
  item: {
    byte_item: {
      type: :CSV,
      data: File.open('/xxxxx/dlptest.csv', 'r').read
    }
  }
}
dlp = Google::Cloud::Dlp.dlp_service
response = dlp.inspect_content(request)
```

Comment: On Excel, support is literally in the middle of launching as we speak. In the next week or two we'll publish updated protocol buffer that will include a new ByteContentItem.EXCEL for that to work.

For CSV, can you include a sample of the CSV here so I can try to test with the same file? Also, including the entire request json payload is super helpful for debugging.

Comment: @JordannaChord I just edited the original post with some more details about the CSV file and the request.  Also, that's very exciting news about the upcoming  ByteContentItem.EXCEL!

Comment: Is it a table inside the CSV file? According to the public documentation, the table method is for structured content for inspection, and Byte_item is for content data to inspect or redact. You can review the code example to inspect a table for sensitive content here: https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/samples/dlp-inspect-table

Comment: @IsmaelClementeAguirre yeah my use case is wanting to take a CSV file, then identify and redact data within it.  I was assuming I could send in a :CSV byte_item type to the inspect function and it would at least find results.  If I have to use a "table" construct, do I need to then inspect with that and then redact the findings and manually recreate the CSV?  I did find this article but I'm not using the Fusion product at the moment:  https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/redacting-confidential-data

Comment: I just tried in a java sample I have to verify this wasn't broken and got it to work in java, so yes CSV files can be passed directly in as a ByteString with type CSV.

I'm not an active ruby developer, but I noticed in our code sample https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/samples/dlp-inspect-file#dlp_inspect_file-ruby the fileOpen command differs a bit. I wonder if the file is corrupted somehow, try logging it to make sure it's your correct test data?

Comment: @JordannaChord I was finally able to get a successful finding using a ByteString and a CSV.  The CSV file I was testing with was something I created using Google Sheets and exported as a CSV, however, the file showed locally as a "text/plain; charset=us-ascii".  I downloaded a random CSV off the internet and it had a mime of "text/csv; charset=utf-8".  This is the one that worked.  So it looks like my issue was specifically due the file being an incorrect mime type.  Thanks a bunch for the help here!

Comment: @dylst If you found the solution to your issue, please post it as an answer to help the community members that may have the same issue as you.

Answer (score 1):

The CSV file I was testing with was something I created using Google Sheets and exported as a CSV, however, the file showed locally as a "text/plain; charset=us-ascii". I downloaded a CSV off the internet and it had a mime of "text/csv; charset=utf-8". This is the one that worked. So it looks like my issue was specifically due the file being an incorrect mime type.

Answer (score 0):

xlsx is not yet supported. Coming soon. (Maybe that part of the question should be split out from the CSV debugging issue.)